# Recommendations for accessibility tools/plugins on Figma

Tags: accessibility, design

My team is striving to **design more accessible solutions** and is actively trying to validate our work.
We tried the paid version of the Stark Plugin, but we're not huge fans of it as it stands currently.

Curious to know if **you have any accessibility plugin recommendations** for Figma